# multi lingual documents in ConTeXt

Tags: input-encodings, context-mkiv

I would like to produce a document (a short article) in `ConTeXt` which is mainly written in Greek.

The problem is that I cannot produce the greek characters. I don't know if I need to define a font that supports the greek language or if I need to specify the encoding at the preamble.

Also I had a look at ConTeXt's [wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Encodings_and_Regimes#In_LaTeX). However, I am still confused.

**Edit:** Here is a mwe

```
\setupbodyfont[genium,12pt]
\starttext
Στο κείμενο αυτό δεν εμφανίζονται οι ελληνικοί χαρακτήρες
\stoptext
```

PS: I compile my document with ConTeXt(LuaTeX)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ConTeXt mkiv, everything is unicode, so you don't need to define an encoding. All you have to do is invoke a font that has Greek characters. The nice Gentium font comes with the minimal distribution, so a minimal document would be:

```
\setupbodyfont[gentium,12pt]
\mainlanguage [gr]

\starttext
Στο κείμενο αυτό δεν εμφανίζονται οι ελληνικοί χαρακτήρες
\stoptext
```

Which gives the expected result.
[image]

Comment: this work for ancient greek. For monotonic (modern greek) i still don't get the greek characters

Comment: Please post a minimal example.

Comment: i just edited my question :)

Comment: You misspelled "gentium" as "genium."

Comment: hahahahhaha... you are right.... false alarm :P